# Merge DataFrames gives unexpected results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm probably overlooking a simple data issue, but I have trouble getting the results what I need when merging dataframes. 
Working from the documentation as listed [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) I would expect all the values from the key column to be present in the merged result with NaN values if the key value isn't present in one of the dataframes;

> If a key combination does not appear in either the left or right
>   tables, the values in the joined table will be NA

However, I'm only getting values for keys that are present in both dataframes for my data. I'm using outer and also tried left (left being the dataframe with more values in the key column). 
When I try it with sample data (created for this question) it somehow seems to work!

```
import pandas as pd import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(0,10, size=(10,)),
                   'Time': np.random.randint(0,10, size=(10,))}) df1 = df1.sort_values('Time')

masterTime = [None]*len(df1) for x in range(len(df1)):
    masterTime[x] = x+1

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Time': masterTime,
                    'B': np.random.randint(0,10,size=(10,))}) 
dfMerged = pd.merge(df1, df2,how='outer',on='Time') 
print(df1) 
print(df2) 
print(dfMerged)
```

this behaves as expected:

```
   A  Time
5  3     0
8  2     0
9  5     0
1  8     2
7  5     4
6  7     5
3  3     6
4  7     6
2  4     7
0  5     9
   Time  B
0     1  1
1     2  8
2     3  9
3     4  1
4     5  5
5     6  0
6     7  9
7     8  6
8     9  1
9    10  6
       A  Time    B
0   0.0     0  NaN
1   9.0     0  NaN
2   8.0     0  NaN
3   2.0     2  5.0
4   4.0     2  5.0
5   9.0     4  2.0
6   0.0     6  8.0
7   9.0     6  8.0
8   8.0     7  1.0
9   5.0     8  6.0
10  NaN     1  8.0
11  NaN     3  5.0
12  NaN     5  4.0
13  NaN     9  9.0
14  NaN    10  2.0
```

However for my source data this gives the following result:

df1:

```
      Time              A              C
0        0      80.332192     136.548522
1        3     100.825094     201.764747
2        5      83.776422     157.963083
3        7      96.326057     207.776248
4        7      98.632962     139.496500
5        8     102.935885     147.342966
6        9      99.895678     167.848140
7       10      77.258792     131.287188
8       10      79.845595     135.395080
9       11      97.838232     192.865211
10      12      78.505035     149.080378
```

df2

```
      Time        B
0        1  1000.12
1        2  1000.12
2        3  1000.12
3        4  1000.12
4        5  1000.12
5        6  1000.12
6        7  1000.12
7        8  1000.12
8        9  1000.12
9       10  1000.12
10      11  1000.12
11      12  1000.12
```

(both dataframes continue like this)

merging these with how='outer' and on='Time' gives me output:

```
       Time              A              C        B
0         0      80.332192     136.548522      NaN
1         3     100.825094     201.764747  1000.12
2         5      83.776422     157.963083  1000.12
3         7      96.326057     207.776248  1000.12
4         7      98.632962     139.496500  1000.12
5         8     102.935885     147.342966  1000.12
6         9      99.895678     167.848140  1000.12
7        10      77.258792     131.287188  1000.12
8        10      79.845595     135.395080  1000.12
9        11      97.838232     192.865211  1000.12
10       12      78.505035     149.080378  1000.12
```

As you can see these are just the values from df1 somehow. No matter if I try left, right, inner or outer, it will always give me these (only difference is it will or will not give me the 0 value depending on the method)
I would expect something like this (in line with the example output above)

```
       Time              A              C        B
0         0      80.332192     136.548522      NaN
1         1            NaN            NaN  1000.12
2         2            NaN            NaN  1000.12
3         3     100.825094     201.764747  1000.12
4         4            NaN            NaN  1000.12
5         5      83.776422     157.963083  1000.12
6         6            NaN            NaN  1000.12 
7         7      96.326057     207.776248  1000.12
8         7      98.632962     139.496500  1000.12
9         8     102.935885     147.342966  1000.12
10        9      99.895678     167.848140  1000.12
11       10      77.258792     131.287188  1000.12
12       10      79.845595     135.395080  1000.12
13       11      97.838232     192.865211  1000.12
14       12      78.505035     149.080378  1000.12
```

The key is 'Time' in both dataframes, so this isn't the issue either. 
Anyone have any clue as to what is going on here?

Comment: You are mixing in different `how` in your question (first example uses `right` and second example uses `outer`), please update and be consistent. Also please submit an example of expected output given your input.

Comment: i've edited the post and included my expected result

Comment: Your expected result doesn't match your input data. For instance: `B` should be `NaN` when `Time` is `12`.

Comment: I've edited my question and added a row for Time is 12, as this is a dataframe with 9000 values or something (for Time 1-9000, with increments of 1, so ALL integers are in there for Time)

Comment: Ok, then `pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer", on="Time")` gives me your expected output.

Comment: yeah so it seems to be a data issue, are there conflicts/different scenarios for certain data types within the dataframe or something?
I checked the keys and 'Time' is indeed in both dataframes (and without any additional space or something). Values in this column are of type  numpy.int64 for both dataframes

Comment: Try forcing them to strings: `df1["Time"] = df1["Time"].astype(str)` and `df2["Time"] = df2["Time"].astype(str)` and then do your merge.

Comment: I'm still getting the same output when I do this..

Comment: No idea what's wrong then, maybe you can add your actual data to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel quite stupid, but it had to do with the sorting. It was working as expected all along, but I failed to properly sort the merged dataframe on 'Time' and therefor the rows for the Time values that weren't in the initial frame weren't showing when printing the merged dataframe. 
Sorting the merged frame in print showed the expected output

```
print(dfMerged.sort_values('Time'))
```